# Rewriting file names according to the available screen space

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

I created a function that rewrites file names according to the available space on screen:

```
@{
  var index = 0;
  foreach (var item in Model)
  {
  <div class="gallery-item">
    <a href="@item.Uri" title="Click to open file" target="_blank" style="display:block; width: 100%;">          
        var id = "filename_" + ++index;
        @Html.SpanFor(i => item.FileName, new { id = id, title = item.FileName, style = "white-space: nowrap;" })          
    </a>
  </div>
  }
}

@section Scripts
{
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function adaptWidth(span) {
      var span = $(span);
      var origfilename = span.text();
      var ext = origfilename.split('.').pop();
      var filename = origfilename.substr(0, origfilename.length - ext.length - 1);
      var text = origfilename;

      while (span.outerWidth() > span.parent().innerWidth()) {
        span.text(text = (filename = filename.substr(0, filename.length - 4) + '...') + ext);
      }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('span[id^=filename_]').each(function (i) { adaptWidth(this) });
    });
  </script>
}
```

Here are the results before and after running script:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

The function runs quite fast for now, but should I be worried from future impact? Any other suggestion or alternatives? Optimization?

I thought about splitting it to 3 spans, 1 for filename, second for `...`, and 3rd for the extension, but I don't really know how to make the overflow of the first be hidden under the other two. Besides, if a truncation isn't required, it's gonna look weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple tweeks for your code. I integrated [@eicto's suggestion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/19915/20138), which is the first step in applying an [interpolated search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search).

```
var $spans = $('span'),
    parentWidth = $spans.first().parent().innerWidth();

$spans.each(function () { 
    adaptWidth(this, parentWidth);
});

function adaptWidth(elm, maxW) {

    // make a var `$elm` so know it's a jQuery object
   var $elm = $(elm),
        // use `lastIndexOf()` to split the filename and
        // extension halves instead of splitting into an array
        fullname = $elm.text(),
        idx = $elm.text().lastIndexOf('.'),
        name = fullname.substr(0, idx),
        ext = fullname.substr(idx),
        // factor is the ratio of the space available for
        // the text vs the space it currently takes up
        factor = maxW / $elm.outerWidth(),
        // idx is a first guess at where the cutoff will be
        idx = (fullname.length+4) * factor;

    idx = Math.round(idx);

    while ($elm.outerWidth() > maxW) {
        name = name.substr(0, --idx);
        $elm.text(name + '...' + ext);
    }
}
```

[The jsFiddle i was testing with.](http://jsfiddle.net/gsHNY/3/)

Edit:

A few edits in the text and, per a comment from the OP, updated the code to determine the max-width only once.

<sub>As a side-note, [apparently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search) this type of search is called an *interpolation-sequential search*.</sub>

Comment: Since the tiles are shared width, I will check its size only once. Answer updated.

Comment: @Shimmy Good to know. I don't see your edit so I added the change.

Answer (score 4):

In general case I would to get text_width and container_width, then `calculate new_string_length=container_width/text_width*length`, than setup increase or decrease text, depending on result_text_width > container_width  and do the loop like yours.

This is really needed only if strings have a very big size.

Comment: 1) It's for filenames, how long can a filename be? I guess not too long. 2) I'm affraid you missed out the whole point, the reason I needed this function is because the font is not a fixed-width one, the width varies between the various characters in it.

Comment: 2) not i not missed, I just think that change length before loop will decrease interations.

Comment: fyi in xfs max filename size is 255 bytes, not sure if it big or not, depend how often you plan call such function